# How to 'git diff-tree' on a certain directory?

Tags: git, gitlab-ci

I need a list of files that changed and dump it to the files

I can get all the list by running this
`git diff-tree --name-status -r "upstream/$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME..HEAD" > changed-files.txt`

But now I want only a list of files that changed inside the `resources` folder only

How to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can target a subdirectory within a commit using the following syntax :

```
<commit hash or name>:path/to/dir
```

In your case, you can change your `git diff-tree` command to :

```sh
git diff-tree --name-status -t \
    "upstream/$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME":resources \
    HEAD:resources
```

---

As @torek comented, you can also simply provide a path after the compared elements, to narrow the diff to that path only, so the following command also works :

```
git diff-tree "upstream/$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME" HEAD -- resources
```

Comment: Note that this literally asks Git to diff the two `resources` sub-trees within the commit. You could also use `git diff-tree <options> <commit1> <commit2> -- resources`, which diffs the top level trees but limits the *reporting* to the `resources` subtree within each top level tree. The effect is the same (and the efficiency should be similar), but using the colon syntax allows you to, e.g., diff commit1's foo/bar subtree vs commit2's baz/raz subtree. Just a side note, really.